# How can I display the second layer of skin on an NPC

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I created an NPC and added the player's skin for it, but the second layer of the skin is not shown. How can i add it to the NPC?
I already found some solutions for newer versions, but they are not working on the 1.8

```java
Location loc = new Location(world, x, y, z, 0, 0);

MinecraftServer minecraftServer = ((CraftServer) Bukkit.getServer()).getServer();
WorldServer worldServer = ((CraftWorld) main.getVotingUtils().world).getHandle();
GameProfile gameProfile = new GameProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), "§6Shop");

for (Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
  EntityPlayer allEntity = ((CraftPlayer) all).getHandle();
  GameProfile allGP = allEntity.getProfile();
  Property skin = allGP.getProperties().get("textures").iterator().next();

  gameProfile.getProperties().put("textures", skin);
  EntityPlayer npc = new EntityPlayer(minecraftServer, worldServer, gameProfile, new PlayerInteractManager(worldServer));
  npc.setLocation(loc.getX(), loc.getY(), loc.getZ(), loc.getYaw(), loc.getPitch());

  PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer) all).getHandle().playerConnection;
  connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, npc));
  connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutNamedEntitySpawn(npc));
  Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(main, () -> {
    connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, npc));
  },5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to send a `PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata` packet with the DataWrapper filled with the corresponding bitmask in https://wiki.vg/Entity_metadata#Player

If you want to enable the cape and the left sleeve for example you will have to set the bitmask as follows:

```java
byte bitmask = (byte) (0x01 | 0x04)
```

and then enter this byte into your DataWatcher which you then wrap in the `PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata` and send to the player for which you just spawned the NPC.

Note that in versions 1.8.x the Index for the displayed skin parts of a player was 10.

So if you want to enable all skin parts you would use this code:

```java
DataWatcher dw = new DataWatcher(null);
dw.a(10, (byte) (0x01 | 0x02 | 0x04 | 0x08 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x40));
PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata packet = new PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata(npc.getId(), dw, true);
connection.sendPacket(packet);
```